# map iterator not incrementable

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

When I try to run my program I get 'map/set iterator not incrementable' error. I read that it happens when you invalidate iterator, but I'm only editing objects pointed by iterator. Is this normal behaviour? What can I do about it?
If I delete this line then there is no error:

```
iterator->second.neighbour[direction] = &(find_iter->second);
```

Full code:

```
void Gomoku::addUniqueMap( const map_Map& map_to_add )
{
    this->unique_maps.push_front( map_to_add );

    std::list<map_Map>::iterator map_iter = this->unique_maps.begin();
    map_Iterator iterator = map_iter->begin();

    for( ; iterator != map_iter->end(); ++iterator )
    {
        for( int i = 1, direction = 0; i > -2; --i )
        {
            for( int j = -1; j < 2; ++j )
            {
                if( iterator->second.neighbour[direction] == nullptr )
                {
                    ++direction;
                    continue;
                }
                if( i == 0 && j == 0 )
                    continue;

                COORD pos( iterator->first.x + j, iterator->first.y + i );
                wrap( pos, this->map_size );

                map_Iterator find_iter = map_iter->find( pos );
                if( find_iter != map_iter->end() )
                {
                    iterator->second.neighbour[direction] = &(find_iter->second);
                }

                ++direction;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

'map_Map' - `std::map<COORD, Pawn>`
'map_Iterator' - `std::map<COORD, Pawn>::iterator`
'Pawn' -

```
struct Pawn
{
    Pawn( Player player );
    Player      player;
    const Pawn* neighbour[8];
};
```

Comment: Can you post the type of `unique_maps` ? You should also try to remove `auto`, the code will be clearer (even if a  bit more verbose)(please use typedefs). Maybe the type deduced by the compiler for the second `auto` is not what we expect, and you are accessing the `end()` iterator... Also, if the size of your map is 1x1, you will have `find_iter` == `iterator`.

Comment: @Synxis I replaced autos with types, but it didn't help.  
And I never access `end()` iterator, I always check first if iterator isn't end().

Comment: Never explicitely setting an iterator to `end()` doesn't mean this iterator cannot take the value of `end()`...

Comment: @Synxis but I check if iterator or find_iter is set to `end()` and if it is then I don't do anything with these iterators, so I shouldn't get runtime error. And I get this error only in debug not in release version.

Comment: Only in debug ? Weirder and weirder... Maybe you have a memory corruption elsewhere in your program.

Comment: @Synxis I found what has been causing this error. I had to write 
`if( i == 0 && j == 0 )
  continue;` before `if( iterator->second.neighbour[direction] == nullptr )
                {
                    ++direction;
                    continue;
                }`. I was modifying iterator->second.neightbour[8]. How can I change question to solved? Or should I delete it?

Comment: You should post an answer to your question and accept it; please explain your solution and the causes of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the error was that I was accessing and modifying `neighbour[8]`, so I was modifying element of out array range and possibly it has done something to the iterator.
In Debug version I got `map/set iterator not incrementable` error while in Release version iterator couldn't be incremented and it caused program to loop infinitely.